# Cannot update during a state transition error - react native using hooks when navigating to another screen

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

Hello i've been trying to fix this all the ways posible still can't find the problem, the problem only appears when the app navigates away to other screen after it finds out that the user already saw the screen for the first time, i was thinking is because when im navigating away the state is still not updated? any help is appreciated.

```
function UserScreen({navigation}) {




    useEffect(() => {        
        checkIfFisrtTime()    
}, [])


    const [name, setname] = useState(undefined)
    const [altura, setaltura] = useState(undefined)
    const [peso, setpeso] = useState(undefined)
    const [hombre, sethombre] = useState(false)
    const [mujer, setmujer] = useState(false)
    const [error, seterror] = useState(undefined)



    const [loading, setloading] = useState(true)
    const [first, setfirst] = useState()


    async function checkIfFisrtTime() {


            const value = await AsyncStorage.getItem("firstLogging")
             setfirst(value)
            setloading(false)


    }


    function check() {
        console.log(first)
        console.log(loading)
    }


if (loading==true && first ==undefined || first==null && loading===true || first=="false" && loading===true || first===undefined && loading ===false)  {


    return (<ActivityIndicator></ActivityIndicator>)

}


if(first==="false" && loading === false ){   


    return navigation.navigate("Mainflow")

}

if (  first==null && loading===false ) {



    return (



        <View style={{ top: height * 0.1, flexDirection: "column", justifyContent: "space-between", height: height * 0.6 }}>



            <Text style={{ textAlign: "center", fontWeight: "bold" }}>{i18n.t("Information")}</Text>
            <CheckBox

                left
                title={i18n.t("Male")}
                checkedIcon='dot-circle-o'
                uncheckedIcon='circle-o'

                checked={hombre}
                onPress={() => { sethombre(true), setmujer(false) }}
                containerStyle={{ width: width * 0.5, alignSelf: "center", borderRadius: 15 }}
                icon
            />

            <CheckBox
                left
                title={i18n.t("Female")}
                checkedIcon='dot-circle-o'
                uncheckedIcon='circle-o'
                checked={mujer}
                onPress={() => { setmujer(true), sethombre(false) }}
                containerStyle={{ width: width * 0.5, alignSelf: "center", borderRadius: 15 }}
            />




            <Input
                placeholder={i18n.t("Age")}
                errorStyle={{ color: 'red' }}
                errorMessage={undefined}
                onChangeText={(name) => { setname(name.replace(/[- #*;,.<>\{\}\[\]\\\/]/gi, '')) }}
                value={name}
                keyboardType="numeric"
                maxLength={2}
                containerStyle={{ width: width * 0.5, alignSelf: "center" }}
                leftIcon={
                    <MaterialCommunityIcons name="vanish" size={24}></MaterialCommunityIcons>
                }
            />

            <Input
                placeholder={i18n.t("Height")}
                errorStyle={{ color: 'red' }}
                errorMessage={undefined}
                onChangeText={(altura) => { setaltura(altura.replace(/[- #*;,.<>\{\}\[\]\\\/]/gi, '')) }}
                value={altura}
                keyboardType="numeric"
                maxLength={3}
                containerStyle={{ width: width * 0.5, alignSelf: "center" }}
                leftIcon={
                    <MaterialCommunityIcons name="arrow-split-horizontal" size={24}></MaterialCommunityIcons>
                }
            />
            <Input
                placeholder={i18n.t("Weight")}
                errorStyle={{ color: 'red' }}

                onChangeText={(namee) => { setpeso(namee.replace(/[- #*;,.<>\{\}\[\]\\\/]/gi, '')) }}
                value={peso}
                keyboardType="numeric"
                maxLength={3}
                containerStyle={{ width: width * 0.5, alignSelf: "center" }}
                leftIcon={
                    <MaterialCommunityIcons name="scale-bathroom" size={24}></MaterialCommunityIcons>
                }
                errorMessage={error}
            />


            <Button title={i18n.t("Continue")} containerStyle={{ width: width * 0.4, alignSelf: "center" }} raised onPress={()=>{ValidateIfundefined()}}>

            </Button>

            <Button title="boton" onPress={()=>{check()}}></Button>



        </View>


    )

    async function ValidateIfundefined() {   

        if (name==undefined && altura==undefined && peso==undefined && hombre==false && mujer==false) {


            //seterror("Please make sure everything is ok")
        }

        if (altura==undefined || peso==undefined || altura==undefined || hombre==false && mujer == false) {


            //seterror("Please fill everything")
        }

        if (name!=undefined && altura!=undefined && peso!=undefined && mujer!=false && hombre==false) {

            await AsyncStorage.setItem("firstLogging","false")
            navigation.navigate("Mainflow")

        }

        if (name!=undefined && altura!=undefined && peso!=undefined && hombre!=false && mujer==false) {
            await AsyncStorage.setItem("firstLogging","false")       
            navigation.navigate("Mainflow")
        }

    }


}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this (example code), possible stack navigator problem

```
componentDidMount() {
     const { navigation } = this.props;
     navigation.addListener('willFocus', () => {
         // this.getListData(); fetch data here
     });
     // this.setState({ listData: data });
}
```

Comment: Still nothing this is getting in my nerves.                                                                                                 
        `useEffect(() => {       
        navigation.addListener('willFocus', async () => {
            const value = await AsyncStorage.getItem("firstLogging")
            checkIfFisrtTime(value)


        }); 
}, [])`